# Place a non String Data Type in putStringSet SharedPreferences Android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

It was an array list at first then I tried changing it into a set so I can place it at putStringSet. But yeah.. It doesn't have a String Datatype

```
    Set<RecordData> set = new HashSet<>(dataList);
      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putStringSet("recordlists", set);
```

The RecordData is a class that I created.

I suck.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: You're correct about converting it into a set, but you're storing it in the wrong way. Check the above mentioned link.

Comment: You can also use Gson library to store and retrieve custom objects - it is explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36184406/3225001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `GSON` library..
try this For saving and loading shared preferences data:

```
public static void saveSharedPreferencesLogList( Set<RecordData> record) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(record);
            prefsEditor.putString("myJson", json);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }


        public static Set<RecordData> loadSharedPreferencesLogList() {
            Set<RecordData> record = new HashSet<>(dataList);

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("myJson", "");
            if (json.isEmpty()) {
                record = new Set<RecordData>();
            } else {
                Type type = new TypeToken<Set<RecordData>>() {
                }.getType();
                record = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            }
            return record;
       }
```

Also place this in your Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```